# Logger Utility in python

Tags: python-3.x, logging

Problem is when i use python from command "from car_logger import log_warning, log_critical, log_error, clear_logs" and execute function log_warning("THIS IS WARNING") , then it works fine i.e log get written to log file and message get displayed on screen due to print command .

But if i am using it via test.py then it print he output on screen as mentioned in function but it does not log warning message in log file ?

Where is mistake?

Here is car_logger.py

```
import logging
from os import remove , path


log_file = "/tmp/robocar_error.log"

my_formatter = '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'

# Create a custom logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Create handlers
f_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file)
f_handler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

# Create formatters and add it to handlers
f_format = logging.Formatter(my_formatter)
f_handler.setFormatter(f_format)

# Add handlers to the logger
logger.addHandler(f_handler)

def log_warning(message):
    print(message)
    logger.warning(message)

def log_critical(message):
    print(message)
    logger.critical(message)

def log_error(message):
    print(message)
    logger.error(message)
```

And here is test.py

```
from car_logger import log_warning, log_critical, log_error, clear_logs
log_warning("THIS IS WARNING")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From line 1 of test.py: `clear_logs` is not defined.
I removed it from test.py and tested: it works fine for me.

Comment: Yes i also find the same  solution .